# Cannot copy file via Python's shutil

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to copy file via Python's shutil. From Python interpreter, started from Powershell, execute:

```
>>> shutil.copy("C:\\Program Files\\1C\\AgentQMC\\1.0.10.2\\file.lock", "C:\\file.lock")
```

(`file.lock` is a file, created by service, which is currently running ) but it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Development\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Development\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 122, in copyfile
    copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
  File "C:\Development\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 79, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I'm sure that I have all necessary permissions, because if i exit Python interpreter and try to copy file via Powershell, it works.

Comment: Because that file is opened somewhere else or you do not have permission to that path. please try manually copying the file.

Comment: @Rahul As I said, I tried copy that file via Powershell, via Explorer, and it works.

Comment: There's an issue with shutil when you try to copyfile in windows while it's open by another program. Try to close the other program and re-run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved. After looking on program's sources (which create this file), I found that this program set exclusive lock on 101th byte (idk why), while actual length of file is less (4-5 bytes, depend of PID value). When I tried to copy this file via Powershell, it `ReadFile` first 4 bytes (actual file length), write them to target file and finish copy sucessful, because it never reach locked region (101th byte). Python for some reason ignore value, which i pass to `.read()` method and reads at least 8192 bytes (I assume that this is some system constant) (but if I pass value `x` more than 8192, it reads exactly `x` bytes). When Python tries to read 8192 bytes from that file, it obviously reach locked region and fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error occur too.
After some testing, it seems that onedrive created the file and wouldn't allow the script access.
Its a specific problem, but figured I would share, because it's something to keep in mind!